# PHP merge variables

Tags: php, merge

How to merge these (make this code shorter)?

```
$match_1 = false;
$match_2 = false;
$match_3 = false;
$match_4 = false;
$match_5 = false;
```

And how to shorter this code:

```
if($match_1 == false) { ... } // if(!$match) must work?
```

Comment: Are you taking an exam? You're asking a lot of similar, simple questions that are worded like exam questions.

Comment: Why do so many people have the fixation that the fewer characters they type, the better their code will be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$match_1 = $match_2 = $match_3 = $match_4 = $match_5 = false;
```

Though using an array might be better

```
$match = array_fill(1,5,false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array:

```
$match = array(false, false, ...);
```

You don't know what you want, but you can check if there's any `false` or `true` elements with:

```
if (in_array(true/false, $match, true)) { ... }
```